# pthread_mutex and process termination

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

Before using a pthread_mutex_t pthread_mutex_init() should be called, and after it's not longer required it should be destroyed using pthread_mutex_destroy().

My question is, what happens if my process terminates before it can call pthread_mutex_destroy(), for example a SIGKILL, SIGINT or SIGABORT? Is it possible that some resource will leak?

Same question goes to pthread_cond_init/destroy as well.

Comment: Why do you think there can be a resource problem? A mutex is just a data structure in user space. When the process terminates, all memory is given back to the OS.

Comment: Your process or a thread? Because when the process terminates all threads finish and the resources are freed.

Comment: @AlainMerigot, that's kind of answer I was looking for, just wanted to be sure.

Comment: @HoracioGoetendiaBonilla, it's the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not on any platform you're likely to use. Objects like mutexes and condition variables are just chunks of memory in the process' address space. When a process terminates, its address space ceases to exist. So it's not possible for any resources to leak.

Process-shared resources are more complex. While the resources won't leak, they may still exist and may even still be in use by other processes.